# TypeError at /student/ HTTP status code must be an integer

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am fetching data from multiple tables to display in template, but getting type error for the same. kindly help me to find the mistake.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.
class quiztitle(models.Model):

    Quiz_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Quiz_title = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    User_id= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class question(models.Model):

    Qid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    User_id = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Quiz_id = models.ForeignKey(quiztitle,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Qques = models.TextField()
    Qoption1 = models.TextField()
    Qoption2 = models.TextField()
    Qoption3 = models.TextField()
    Qoption4 = models.TextField()
    QAnswer = models.TextField()

class answer(models.Model):

    Ansid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    Qid = models.ForeignKey(question,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Quiz_id = models.ForeignKey(quiztitle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    User_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Answer = models.TextField()
```

may be i have not implemented correct logic in views.py
views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['Student'])
def handle_response(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        myuser = User.objects.all()
        title = quiztitle.objects.all()
        data = question.objects.all()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            Answer=request.POST.get('Answer')
            response = answer(Answer=Answer)
            response.User_id = request.user
            response.Quiz_id = request.quiztitle
            response.Qid = request.question
            Answer.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/student')

    return render(request, "student.html", {"messages":data},{"topic":title},{"user1":myuser})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the context data in the wrong way. Replace your return statement as

```
return render(
    request,
    "student.html",
    context={
        "messages": data,
        "topic": title,
        "user1": myuser
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

replace tis line :

```
return render(request, "student.html", {"messages":data},{"topic":title},{"user1":myuser})
```

with this:

```
return render(request, "student.html", {"messages":data,"topic":title,"user1":myuser})
```